# convert a string to a sequence of C# Unicode character literals

Tags: c#, string, unicode, char, literals

I'm looking for a way to convert a string into a sequence of Unicode character literals in C#.

For example:

Input:

```
Hi!
```

Output:

```
\u0048\u0069\u0021
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean you want that output as string, you can iterate through all the characters get their Unicode hex values:

```
const string value = "Hi!";

var chars = value
    .Select(c => (int) c)
    .Select(c => $@"\u{c:x4}");

var result = string.Concat(chars);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LUO5Gw) for a working demo.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the same approach, implemented with StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in s)
    sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X4}",(uint)c);
return sb.ToString();
```